# SQL Daily updating table

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine two tables. One is updated daily, the other is needed to store data from the table that is updated daily perpetually. However the primary key ranges from 1-n with N being variable. Meaning that new things might be added to this row whenever. However once added these do not change.

My question really can be summed up into how do i do this best?

The current way i am thinking off is that i want the key to be the first column, and then adding a column on daily storing the data as needed, while naming the column the todays date.

Comment: Why not develop a code example like, it is already clearer than to write a pavement and let people imagine a situation that you have in your head ...

Comment: Question seems a bit unclear. How is the data being used in the second table? Is that a backup table?

Comment: Okay, that is my mistake if it is unclear. The tables are to be used as a method for storing product information, and warehouse movement information. So that i can track quantities in warehouses throughout time.  This is why my primary key might change as new products are added, and i suggested a new row.

Answer (score 0):

I also think exactly like you. Just add one column named batch_no or xx_date and store corresponing date and make composite key.